# Sound quit working - although VOIP works with headset

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have a Compaq pc with Windows 7 64 bit.  I am getting no audio from speakers.  I do hear a clicking noise when I plug in or touch the audio cable/jack coming thru the speakers.  I have upgraded drivers and checked the bios.  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

right click the sound icon in your Task Tray (next to the clock).  Select Playback devices.  Make sure your speakers are selected as the default sound device (should have a green check).  If not, right click the speakers and select default sound device.

Answer (score 0):

Noise in the way you describe it suggests a bad physical connection, most likely a problem with the receptacle in the computer rather than the cable.

You could try another cable first, but ....

Comment: That noise is typical when plugging into a powered source

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a duplicate question to me, but could be coincidence.  In any case: go into Control Panel > Sound.  Click the Communications tab & change from "reduce the volume of other sounds" to "Do nothing".  And if this resolves your problem (since you say the sound is OK on VOIP calls) then I'll have to find out where that other question was, and upvote the person who wrote this answer originally!